# Why my code of problem 12 of projecteuler.net didnt work?

Tags: python

So I wrote this in python

```
condition = True
sum = 0
i = 0
arr = []
while condition:
   i = i + 1
   sum = sum + i
   #print(i, sum)
   for x in range(1,sum+1):

       if sum%x == 0:
           arr.append(x)
   if len(arr)>=500:
       result = sum
       condition = False
   else:
       arr = []
print(arr, result)
```

But it never ends! Any idea of what has happened to my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the loop runs infinitely.

```
   if len(arr)>=500:
       result = sum
       condition = False
   else:
       arr = []
```

this if else condition runs for the else part in every iteration and reinitialises the array hence its length is set to 0..
iteration keeps on happening and the array keeps on reinitialising hence the loop runs infinitely as the if part never gets satisified.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you're checking to see if arr is greater than 500 you're wiping it out if it isn't, which means it never is.